# uWsgi nginx integration error

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am using `uWsgi` to deploy my `django` site here is my `uWsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
socket=/var/run/uwsgi.sock
virtualenv=/root/edupalm/env/
chdir=/root/edupalm/edupalm
master=True
workers=8
pidfile=/var/run/uwsgi-master.pid
max-requests=5000
module=edupalm.wsgi:application
```

and using nginx, here is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen       9000;
    server_name  162.243.146.127;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/edupalm_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/edupalm_error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /root/edupalm/edupalm/static/;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass      unix:///var/run/uwsgi.sock;
    }

}
```

but I am having `502 Bad Gateway`

here is the logs:

nginx:

```
2013/11/26 08:31:09 [error] 1758#0: *57 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 197.160.112.183, server: 162.243.146.127, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///var/run/uwsgi.sock:", host: "162.243.146.127:9000"
```

uwsgi:

```
-- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
```

`nginx` is running on user `www-data` and `uwsgi` is running as `root`

Comment: what is in your uwsgi logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's advisable to use new user for your project, not root

The problem is in configuration, you should to add

```
plugin=python
```

for permissions it's better to use www-data user/group:

```
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
chmod-socket = 777
chown-socket = www-data
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a distribution package instead of official uWSGI sources. Just load (after having installed it) the python plugin with plugin = python in your config

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {  
    uwsgi_pass      unix:///var/run/uwsgi.sock;  
    include         uwsgi_params;  
    uwsgi_param     SCRIPT_NAME '';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I similarly had this problem for a combination of Django, uWSGI and nginx running behind CloudFront. It turned out for me that the routing table in CloudFront didn't behave as expected, so some of the callbacks weren't received.

Specifically, route "/" stole traffic from "*".

There was another issue where my Django server was running unexpected code; as a user logging in caused their User model to be changed, which I hadn't predicted for some reason. So yeah, don't rule out that your Django server might be legitimately busy, causing a timeout of the socket.